# Every time i try running this code it just returns [string “<eval>“]:7: “then expected near ‘=’ ” assistance please

Tags: lua

So I’m trying to do some kind of help system where if the player types ‘help’ it will return “alright what do you need help with?” And if the player types anything else it returns something.

This is the script:

```
print("Hi, welcome to Liminality.This is a horror game so be prepared. If you need anyhelp, just type'help'.Thanks for trying out our game!")
local help = io.read()

if help == "help" then do
print("alright, what do you need help with?")
end

elseif help =~ "help" then do
print("no")

end
```

Comment: It's `~=` instead of `=~`. And you need another `end` at the end.

Comment: Also there is no need for `do...end` blocks in `if`.

Answer (score 0):

In if statements you should not use "do" at the end, You will probably use it mostly for "for" loops.
If you use "elseif" then you should continue the if statement and add just one "end" at the end of the condition; also you can use how many elseif you like. Lastly if you use "else" then you should not write any condition for it because it's supposed to be the last one.

```
if ( ) then
    *action you want to perform*
elseif ( ) then
    *another action you want to perform*
else
    *last action you want to perform*
end
```

I corrected the code and you can see i removed the "do" and the "end".
I also corrected the "not equal" sign to "~="

```
print("Hi, welcome to Liminality. This is a horror game so be prepared. If you 
need anyhelp, just type'help'.Thanks for trying out our game!")
local help = io.read()

if (help == "help") then
print("alright, what do you need help with?")
elseif (help ~= "help") then
print("no")
end
```

Because you have only 1 if statement and than 1 opposite i would have done it like this:

```
print("Hi, welcome to Liminality. This is a horror game so be prepared. If you 
need anyhelp, just type'help'.Thanks for trying out our game!")
local help = io.read()

if (help == "help") then
print("alright, what do you need help with?")
else
print("no")
end
```